# Microsoft graph api events call doesnt receive master events

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I've noticed that when I run the code using my personal delegate token, everything works as expected, and it successfully retrieves all the master events. However, when I switch to using the application token, I no longer receive the master events.

To troubleshoot, I verified the token scope using jwt.io and confirmed that it contains the correct permissions. This leads me to wonder: why does the code function properly with delegated tokens but not with application tokens?

```
`var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.Read" }`;

        var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
        {
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
        };

        var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(TenantId, ClientId, ClientSecret, options);
        var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(scopes);
        var accessToken = await clientSecretCredential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext);
        var eventsList = new List<Event>();
        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
        var result = await graphClient.Users[userId].Events.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
        {
            requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string []{ "subject","seriesMasterId","type","recurrence","start","end" };
            
        });
       
     
        var events = await graphClient.Users[userId].Calendar.Events.GetAsync();
```

Comment: Did you configure any application access policy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access or simply set `Calendars.Read` application policy in Azure (Entra) portal? Only for clarification...the events where the value of the property `type` is set to `seriesMaster` are not returned?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that when using an application token, Microsoft Graph will not return master recurring events by default. It will only return event instances.

To retrieve the master recurring events with an application token, you need to specify `$expand=seriesMaster` in the query parameters.

So your code would become:

```cs
var result = await graphClient.Users[userId].Events.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>  
{
  requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string []{ "subject","seriesMasterId","type","recurrence","start","end" };
  requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new [] { "seriesMaster" };
});
```

This will expand the seriesMaster property and return the master recurring events along with the instances.

The reason for this difference in behavior is that delegated tokens are tied to a specific user, so Microsoft Graph assumes you want all their events including recurring masters. Application tokens are not associated with a user, so Microsoft Graph returns a more limited set of event data by default.

**So in summary:**

- Delegated token: Returns master recurring events by default
- Application token: Need to specify `$expand=seriesMaster` to get master recurring events

Comment: This doesn't work. Adding $expand=seriesMaster reutrns: "BadRequest: Parsing OData Select and Expand failed: Could not find a property named 'seriesMaster' on type 'microsoft.graph.event'."